# Why is my BufferedImage different when drawn to canvas?

Tags: java, javafx, bufferedimage

Original

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B3xxfWkGsMs2_MQ_bUQ8_ALYI0DL-LIo/view?usp=sharing

When saved to file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z5euXupeHmiFebch4A39fVqGukoUiK0p/view?usp=sharing

When printed to canvas

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VouD-ygf0pPXFFx9Knr4pv44FHMtoqcV/view?usp=sharing

```
BufferedImage temp = bImg.getSubimage(100, 100, (int)imgWidth - 100, (int)imgHeight - 100);
    try{
        ImageIO.write(temp, "png", new File("test.png"));
     }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     gc.drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(temp, null), 100, 100);
```

For some reason if I print an image to the canvas, it is different than if I save the same image to a file. When I save it to a file it correctly calculates the subImage but when I print it to the canvas it disregards the x and y coords I give it and takes a subImage using (0,0) as (x,y) with the given width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation of the getSubimage method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,int,int,int%29):

> Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned `BufferedImage` shares the same data array as the original image.

The sub-image is just a “window” into the original image;  they are using the same pixel data.

The [SwingFXUtils.toFXImage documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) states:

> Snapshots the specified `BufferedImage` and stores a copy of its pixels into a JavaFX `Image` object, creating a new object if needed.

While it would certainly make sense to only copy the pixels in the source image’s dimensions, the above words don’t make it completely clear that it won’t copy the entire pixel data buffer, thus ignoring the boundaries of a sub-image.  I would consider this a bug, but I can see where there might be an argument that it’s not.

In the meantime, you can work around this by extracting a sub-image yourself:

```
BufferedImage cropped = new BufferedImage(
    (int) imgWidth - 100,
    (int) imgHeight - 100,
    bImg.getType());

Graphics g = cropped.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(bImg, -100, -100, null);
g.dispose();

gc.drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(cropped, null), 100, 100);
```

Comment: I looked at a similar problem some time ago, and studied the source code for `SwingFXUtils`. I also concluded this is a bug. I don't see any use case where the current behavior would be useful...